# I am using Typescript to update the database

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am using Typescript to update the database but before executing an update, I validate that the data types align correctly. Only the values that have changed are updated, and certain fields are restricted from being modified.

But I am getting an error:

```
Type 'string | number | boolean' is not assignable to type 'never'.
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.ts(2322)
const changedFields: Partial<User>

on line :-  changedFields[key as keyof Partial<User>] = newValue;
```

```
// Determine which fields have changed and validate data types
      const changedFields: Partial<User> = {};
      const validationErrors: Error[] = [];
      for (const key in values) {
          if (!restrictedFieldsToUpdate.includes(key)) {
              const newValue = values[key as keyof Partial<User>]; // Type assertion here
              const existingValue = existingUser[key as keyof Partial<User>]; // Type assertion here
              if (newValue !== existingValue) {
                  if (typeof newValue !== typeof existingValue) {
                      validationErrors.push(new Error(`Data type mismatch for field ${key}`));
                  } else {
                    
                      changedFields[key as keyof Partial<User>] = newValue; // Type assertion here
                      
                  }
              }
          } else {
              validationErrors.push(new Error(`Field '${key}' cannot be updated`));
          }
      }
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying and what your issue is. could you please [edit] your question and make some changes. for example your title is a statement not a question. Which database is being updated (pgsql/mysql/oracle/mongodb) and what is your tech stack? is there a backend or is this running on the server?

Comment: the issue is clearly the error message thrown on the line `changedFields[key as keyof Partial<User>] = newValue` .. so it means ts cannot trust newValue to be of a type that can be assigned to `changedFields` properties. To quickly address that very specific issue you may try `newValue as User[keyof User];` in the right hand part of the assignment

Comment: What's the type of `values`?